# How do I prove this? $∀ k, n ∈ℤ , \text{ if } \ k \mid n^2, \text{ then }k \mid n$ .

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would appreciate if someone could take me through the steps. I did not find an counterexamples.

Comment: Is "n2"$\;=n^2\;$ ?

Comment: this is not true: take $n=2$ and $k=4$.

Answer (score 3):

It is false if that's a square:

$$8\mid 4^2\;,\;\;\text{but}\;\;8\nmid 4\;\ldots$$

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I did not consider this. Thank you.